# How to add a variable in a url

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api

Am trying to add a variable into a url, but the server gives me a 400 and i dont recive data

```
var x = "City"
$.getJSON('http://api.apixu.com/v1/current.json?key=' + x, function(jd) {
```

Comment: It appears you are missing a closing parenthesis `)`.

Comment: This is a dummy example

Answer (score 0):

You can just merge multiple strings and then use this in your JSON request:

```
var x = "City";
var y = function(jd);
var prefixURL = "http://api.apixu.com/v1/current.json?key=";
var finalURL = prefixURL.concat(x, y);

$.getJSON(finalURL {
```

You can also merge these into a single line:

```
var finalURL = "http://api.apixu.com/v1/current.json?key=".concat("city", function(jd));
```

If you're feeling brave:

```
$.getJSON("http://api.apixu.com/v1/current.json?key=".concat("city", function(jd))) {
```

Side note: Check the output of your function is what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you did not even read the documentation provided by [Apixu](https://www.apixu.com/)...

Do you know what an API key is? It is an identifier that a service gives you after your subscription, so that it can identify your application when you send some requests. "City" is certainly not an API key. It is a simple parameter to query the API.

Please take a look at the Apixu website to know your API key. If you do not inject it in the request, you will obviously face a 401 status code (Unauthorized).

By the way, you do not even have to code to test this API. There is an interactive API explorer: https://www.apixu.com/api-explorer.aspx

Comment: I wont put my API key, I do know how to use it and the City is just a variable, I can change it with New York or Paris

Comment: No, "City" is a string that you assigned to your variable x. So with your concatenation, your URL contains "?key=City".